# Secure python web app

Tags: python, security, web-applications

i have python web app build on top of BaseHTTPServer, which runs on specyfic port. It runs system commands and shows output. I want do limit access to this app. What are posible ways to do it? Requirements:

- it must not be limited to LAN
- simple to implement/deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest and most secure: Put Apache or Nginx in front of it with an HTTPS proxy.

Update: Or VPN access as suggested by Jakob. Good idea.

Comment: :D thanks, personally I run everything in my house over a ssh tunnel. With some nasty little kinks in the network to stop people opening the front door... On the other hand these defenses are a little harsh for a production system

Comment: @Jakob: Yeah, security by "kinks" needs to be documented in a production system, which makes it much less secure.

Comment: I totally agree. That and you can't have a script that removes a production server from the web if its attacked, it kind of makes it pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Common methods: VPN access. Firewalls, logging, denyhosts style defences, complicated root passwords, no su, run as its own user.

(if it was my personal server)
Logic bombs